# How do I split/slice a leaflet L.layerGroup into mutliple L.layerGroup(s)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, javascript-objects

I'm using leafletjs to draw a line from marker to marker. But the markers are grouped into sets, each with its own name. I get the data from MySQL with PHP and create;

`var OBJMarkerList = L.layerGroup([W0DLK01,W0DLK02,W0DLK03,W0DLK04,W0DLK05,WA0TJT01,WA0TJT02,WA0TJT03,WA0TJT04,WA0TJT05,WA0TJT06,WA0TJT07,WA0TJT08,WA0TJT09,]);`

Notice the name changes.
But I need to pass it into a function one part at a time in order to change the color of the line. So while I have the above OBJMarkerList what I really need is;

```
var W0DLKOBJMarkerList = L.layerGroup([W0DLK01,W0DLK02,W0DLK03,W0DLK04,W0DLK05,]);
```

And another for the other set of values, WA0TJTOBJMarkerList.
I created an array of the names;

```
const allnameBounds = (['W0DLKOBJMarkerList','WA0TJTOBJMarkerList']);
```

But its literally just the names and the function (below) will not accept it as input to convert to the x,y coordinates I need.

```
function connectTheDots(data){
            var c = [];
            for(i in data._layers) {
                var x = data._layers[i]._latlng.lat;
                var y = data._layers[i]._latlng.lng;
                c.push([x, y]);
            }
            return c;
        }
```

How can I split the L.layerGroup into two or any number of parts based on the variable names given? There will usually be more than just two, this is a simplified example.

I tried iterating over the allnameBounds array in all the usual ways and while the looping works to extract the name, the function does not process it like the leaflet object it is.

I also went back to the MySQL/PHP and tried to create a stand alone for each name, that's fine but I still need another list of the L.layerGroup names to iterate over.

Spliting or slicing the combined seemed the only answer. I just don't know how to get there.

Can someone give me a better way or show me how to split the overall list?

Comment: I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. You don't want to group markers *based on the names of the variables their data is stored into*, but rather based on some characteristic available in the MySQL DB. I think you should go to the PHP code that assigns variable names, and store the markers into *arrays* (one array per category/layergroup) instead of assigning different names.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I appreciate that thought but unfortunately I would still need a variable containing each of the names assigned. That variable (array) would then need to be looped over to run the code. But Javascript resolves the name but not the object it actually represents. Hence my reason for asking to split or slice the entire list. The name I was going for is easy to see based on the content, nothing more.

Comment: I still find it hard to understand why you *need* named variables for each marker; it's also difficult to understand the logic without seeing the PHP part that creates the variable names based on DB data.

Comment: @ivanSanchez I'm probable not explaining this very well, for that I apologize. I don't need named variables for EACH marker just for the group of markers. The group can be named using the first part of each marker name.

Comment: @IvanSanchez This hand edited page source demonstrates what I'm after.  https://net-control.us/pagesource.php